# Accord d’« être garanti + infinitif »

Tags: adjectifs, accord, infinitif

Je n'ai aucune hésitation à accorder

> Ces montres sont garanties neuves.

mais face à

> Ces montres sont garanti(es?) ne pas s’arrêter avant deux ans.

accorder me gène (je prononce les voyelles finales suivies d'un e muet comme des voyelles longues, donc pour moi il y a bien une différence audible entre accorder et pas).  Est-ce que mon oreille m’égare ou il y a-t-il une bonne raison de ne pas accorder ici?

Comment: Perso je doute de la tournure « garantir (ou être garanti) + infinitif » elle-même. Le TLF ne la mentionne pas. Ngrams n'en reporte que d'[infimes traces](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=garantir_INF+être%2C+garantir_INF+avoir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19).

Answer (score 2):

Ici la forme correcte de la phrase est "Ces montres sont garanties **de** ne pas s'arrêter avant deux ans."

Garanties au pluriel car le sujet de la phrase est "Ces montres".

Et l'utilisation du "de" pour accorder car ici garanties est utilisé comme l'action d'être garanties. Ex : De quelle fonctionnalités ces montres sont-elles garanties ? De ne pas s'arrêter avant deux ans !

Comment: Euh... "être garanti de" sonne vraiment bizarre. Je "vous garantis que" je n'ai jamais entendu cette tournure. Un objet "garanti pour" X ans, ok aussi.

Comment: Je peux vous assurer que "être garanti de" est une tournure française bien réelle. Je vous garantis de la véracité de mes propos ;)

Comment: @Alex Ce n'est pas la même construction. Dans un cas, on a « <garant> garantit de <affirmation> ». Dans l'autre, <objet> est garanti de <action-à-l'infinitif> (où *garanti* est un adjectif, pas un participe passé puisque il n'y a pas de tournure active « *je garantis ces montres de ne pas s'arrêter »).

Comment: Et d'ailleurs on dit « je vous garantis la véracité de mes propos », le verbe *garantir* est transitif direct dans ce cas. Mais on doit bien en être au niveau du [registre relâché](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/prescriptivist-vs-descriptivist-prescriptif-ou-descriptif/155#155) pour « garantir de quelque chose » dans le sens de « garantir quelque chose » (alors que le sens « protéger de quelque chose » est désuet).

Comment: Certes, merci pour vos lumières ;) Il est vrai que lorsqu'il n'y a pas de verbe à l'infinitif derrière le verbe garantir, le verbe devient transitif direct, mais dans le cas d'un verbe à l'infinitif, le mot de liaison "de" est autorisé.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne vois aucune raison qui pousserait à ne pas accorder.

Ces montres sont garanties deux ans.
Ces montres sont garanties contre les vices cachés.
Ces montres sont garanties inusables.
Ces montres sont garanties ne pas s'user.

> Elles étaient garanties résister aux vents jusqu'à 200 kilomètres à l'heure. ([Heather Graham, trad. Pierre Vandeplanque](http://books.google.fr/books?id=XjXCwsn8zY4C&pg=PT126&dq=%22garanties+r%C3%A9sister%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=PlUXU_XrBsf9ygPhoIHAAw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22garanties%20r%C3%A9sister%22&f=false))

La construction est rare, mais pas inexistante.

[image: garantis _VERB_,garantis de _VERB_]

Ne pas confondre « garantir quelque chose » (affirmer que quelque chose se produira, ou affirmer une garantie concernant un objet) avec « garantir de quelque chose » (affirmer qu'un évènement ne se produira pas, quelque peu vieilli, proche de « garantir contre »). Voir le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garantir), sens et construction A/B. « Garantir de » dans le sens de « garantir » au lieu de « garantir contre » a toutefois tendance à se répandre, mais pas encore au point que je le considérerais comme correct — comparer [« garanti résister »](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22garanti+r%C3%A9sister%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (actuellement 27 résultats) et [« garanti de résister »](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22garanti+de+r%C3%A9sister%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (actuellement 16 résultats) — à ce niveau, on atteint [registre relâché](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/prescriptivist-vs-descriptivist-prescriptif-ou-descriptif/155#155).

Comment: Je ne vois pas de raison non plus, sauf que ma prononciation utilise un i long dans les trois premières phrases et pas la quatrième.  (Et naturellement, au bout d'un moment je sature et hésite pour tout)

Comment: « Se garantir du soleil » c'est une construction sans proposition infinitive. Tu laisses croire que « garantir de + infinitif » puisse avoir ce sens. Autrement, je suis certain d'avoir entendu et lu cette construction plusieurs fois, et ça me choque toujours (je ne suis donc pas étonné de ne pas la trouver dans le TLF). Sinon, plutôt que d'un registre relâché, je dirais que ça provient d'un registre mercantile qui — probablement par nécessité de concision — se soucie peu du français.

Comment: Par ailleurs `garantis _VERB_` ça se trouve dans des phrases toutes simples ou *garantis* qualifie un sujet qui indépendamment de cette qualité fait une action.